# How to uninstall microsoft office 2007 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

The office files got deleted from my C:\ProgramFiles now i can not uninstall it from control panel.

Its showing an error message like

```
   Setup cannot continue because a required file is either corrupted or not available.
   Run Setup again from the original source disc or download location
```

i can not re install . its showing the same error during re installing.

Please post me a way to uninstall the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to manually uninstall the 2007 Office system if you cannot uninstall it by using the "Add or Remove Programs" feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218)

> This article describes how to uninstall the existing 2007 Microsoft Office system if you cannot uninstall it by using the Add or Remove Programs feature (or Programs and Features in Windows Vista) in Control Panel. We recommend that you verify that you cannot uninstall by using Add or Remove Programs first

Answer (score -1):

The most lamest solution is reinstall MS Office 2007 and than remove it using uninstaller.

The second (smartest) way is to visit [Microsoft Support [KB290301]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) and scroll down there a page and download (button Fix it) automatic clean up utility for specific Microsoft Office edition (I mean 2003,2007 or 2010).